# matplotlib not plotting scientific data correctly in py3

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot spectral data.

Want to migrate it to py3.  Same code does NOT work in py3 - plot fails to properly show the y-axis.  Data is a CSV that contains pairs of intensity values and wavelengths; first few lines shown here:

3540.2490,4.632113e-16

3541.9949,8.944044e-16

3543.7408,6.277130e-16

3545.4867,9.707854e-16

3547.2326,7.374052e-16

.......

Total length of file is ~2500 lines - hardly 'big data'

The following code works perfectly in py27.  But in py3, code shows y-scale as 10^0, 10^1 etc instead of 10^-16 etc.  Other problem (or clue?) is that what takes ~1 sec in py27 takes 30-40sec in py3

Cannot find any solution to this.

```
# Function to do the plotting ...
def action():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialfile="*.csv",title = cPrompt)
    if filename:
       print(filename)
    cXAxisText = cXAxis.get()    
    cYAxisText = cYAxis.get()
    cTitleText = cTitle.get()
    bXLog = bXAxis.get()
    bYLog = bYAxis.get()
    f = open(filename, "r")
    data = f.read()
    data = data.split('\n')
    x = [row.split(',')[0] for row in data]    #using separator as defined in Excel
    y = [row.split(',')[1] for row in data]    #using separator as defined in Excel
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.set_title(cTitleText)
    ax1.set_xlabel(cXAxisText)
    ax1.set_ylabel(cYAxisText)
    ax1.grid()
    ax1.plot(x,y, c='r')
    if bXLog >0:                # Scale x-axis as log
        ax1.set_xscale('log')
    if bYLog >0:                # Scale y-axis as log
        ax1.set_yscale('log')
    plt.show()

# Values such as cXAxisText, bXlog etc are values in a tkinter form
```

Comment: Did you print out `x` and `y` to see whether they made sense? Did you try to use [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)? Maybe `data.split('\n')` doesn't work for this particular file?

Comment: The principal problem seems to be that `row.split(',')[0]` is of type string, and that in Python3 you explicitly need to convert it to a float: `float(row.split(',')[0])`. `pd.read_csv()` could be helpful to automatically do the tricky stuff.

Comment: Many thanks Johan, your suggestion did the trick spot on.  Couple of moments along the way.  First was 'Cannot convert string to float.  Turned out I had one extra bit of data wrangling to do (there was a blank record at the end of the CSV).  Second was it wouldn't plot the data until I killed the tkinter instance (in a jupyter notebook).
In answer to your other points,  yes I had printed x, y out and they seemed OK.  That's why I couldn't figure out the problem.  
Thanks once again.